# How can I post with a HTTP body properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-headers, http-post

I have a method in iOS where all I'm trying to do is to perform a `POST` with a simple `NSDictionary` in `HTTP` Body. Here is what I return with `rac_POST`.

```
return [[[self rac_POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"reservations/%@/update",reservationID] parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){
   [formData appendPartWithHeaders:@{@"Content-Type":@"application/json"} body:jsonData];
   [formData appendPartWithFormData:jsonData name:@"payload"];

}] map:^id(RACTuple *t) {
    RACTupleUnpack(NSDictionary * result) = t;
    return result;
}] catch:^RACSignal *(NSError *error) {
       return [self customErrorSignal:error];
}];
```

I've tried so many ways but it's just not `POSTING` through my `API` properly. I am converting my `NSDictionary` to `NSData` like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *payloadDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[payloadDict setObject:payloadArray forKey:@"payload"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:payloadDict];
```

What am I missing in my method?

I've also tried adding the `body` (`payloadDict` in my code above) to my parameters `dictionary` and it did not work. According to our internal `API` documents, it specifically said to add the `payloadDict` as part of the `HTTP` Body. Can someone also clarify if this makes a difference at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert NSDictionary  to NSData using this way

```
NSData  *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization  dataWithJSONObject:questionDict options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: [formData appendPartWithHeaders:@{@"Content-Type":@"application/json"} body:jsonData]; Is this the correct method to use to append to Body? or should I be using [formData appendPartWithFormData:jsonData name:@"payload"];

Comment: I've changed it to NSJSONSerialization, but I'm still getting an error

Comment: you can try to remove this line [formData appendPartWithFormData:jsonData name:@"payload"]; and check again

Answer (score 0):

If Your service accept json format of data then you should use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert root object to data instead of `NSKeyedArchiver`.